# Spring+Hibernate: How to handle Multiply (Unlimited) Data Sources and Session Factories dynamically?

Tags: spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

Our application may have multiply databases. Databases may be different type (Oracle and MS SQL) for the same application instance. Databases structures are slightly different but the same set of Hibernate POJOs are used. List od databases can be determined only when the application actually starts (so it cannot be stored as a fixed XML)

User needs to choose a DB during login process. The chosen DB is stored in HTTP Session.

So I'd like to use Sping auto-wiring to have Session Factory auto-wired to my DAOs in Web controllers depends on the current user. Like:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@Controller
public abstract class UserGroupDAO {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public List<Users> getListOfUsers() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.currentSession();
        return session.createCriteria(Users.class).list();
    }
}


@Controller
public class WebController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userGroupDAO")
    private UserGroupDAO userGroupDAO;  

    @RequestMapping("/greeting.html")
    public ModelAndView greeting(Model model) {
        userGroupDAO.getListOfUsers();
    }
```

For example: there are 2 DBs - Oracle_DB and MS_SQL_DB and two users A and B. User A logged in Oracle_DB, User B logged in MS_SQL_DB. When User A hits /greeting he should see list of users from Oracle_DB, when User B hits /greeting - from MS_SQL_DB.

I reviewed AbstractRoutingDatasource, but it looks like it works only for a single Session Factory with multiply Data Sources. However I am looking for an need individual Session Factory for each Data Source (and Transaction manager too).

Thank you in advance for help

**Problem Summary**

Databases are generated dynamicaly thus cannot hard code database settings into config file. Spring application needs to be able to determine which databases are available and then connect to them.

Comment: Can you reword your post into a question? Most people skim questions and won't reply if they can't figure out what you're asking.

Comment: What you want is some form of multi tenancy. A solution I used years ago for a client was documented [here](http://mdeinum.wordpress.com/2007/01/05/one-application-per-client-database/). The code is available on [github](https://github.com/mdeinum/spring-utils) you would be interested in the `multi-tenant` project.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was
1) Set UserGroupDAO, SessionFactory, etc. scope to 'session'

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@Scope(value="session",proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS) 
public class UserGroupDAO extends GeneralDAO {
```

2) Initialize SessionFactory, Session, etc. manually in a Singleton (DataSourceProvider) and get it from this Singleton in ApplicationContextConfig

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(....)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationContextConfig {
    @Autowired
    @Bean("sessionFactory")
    @Scope(value="session")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    return DataSourceProvider.getInstance().getDatasourceByContext().getSessionFactory();
    }
    @Autowired
    @Bean("dataSource")
    @Scope(value="session")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return DataSourceProvider.getInstance().getDatasourceByContext().getDataSource();
    }
```

3) Detect the current DB inside DataSourceProvider

```
public class DataSourceProvider {

private static DataSourceProvider instance = new DataSourceProvider();

public static DataSourceProvider getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

private HashMap<String, MyDataSource> dataSources;

private DataSourceProvider(){
}

public MyDataSource getDatasourceByContext() {
    String connectionName;
    if (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() instanceof ServletRequestAttributes) {
        ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        HttpServletRequest request = attributes.getRequest();
        if (request==null) {
            connectionName = null;
        } else {
            //"currentDatabase" is set during logon
            connectionName = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("currentDatabase");
        }
    } else {
        connectionName = null;
    }
    if (connectionName!=null) {
        MyDataSource dataSource = dataSources.get(connectionName);
        if (dataSource != null) {
            return dataSource;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("No datasource for the context");
}
```